# how display view when cells select in a tableview

Tags: iphone

i am new to iphone ,my question is in one view i placed a tableview and display some data on that view,i want to add another view(same view to all cell) when select cell(suppose select first cell view will display and newly add view is used to delet that cell information based on cell index)please tell me how to display view.

Comment: Can you please be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in your TableView class; that is where you deal with the selected row. Here is some code that pushes a webViewController onto the screen :

```
webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *temp = [eventsDict objectForKey:[datesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];
EventObject *tempEvent = [temp objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSString *eventURL = [tempEvent eventLink];        
[wvc setEventWebsite:eventURL];
[self setWebViewController:wvc];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
[wvc release];
[webViewController release];
```

Basically I have an array of Events, it gets the event you touched using [indexPath row], gets the URL within that Event object, passes it to the webViewController, then it pushes the webViewController onto the screen loading the appropriate link. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the same view for all cells - simply create one UIView object and change frame in didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method. It will something like this -
At first declare infoView in your .h file UIView *infoView, next steps:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
infoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
infoView.hidden = YES;
[tableView addSubview:infoView];
[super viewDidLoad];    }  

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGPoint st = CGPointMake(tableView.frame.size.width/2, cell.frame.size.height*indexPath.row);
infoView.hidden = NO;
infoView.center = st;}
```

Don't forget to release infoView in dealloc method